# Pandas - Filling in blank cells in a column with 0 causing the entire column to go blank

Tags: python, pandas

Good Afternoon,

I have constructed a vlookup between 2 dataframes and this works provided that the event_id column has a code in it. Where this falls apart is when no event_id is present, the result being that the SrcCode and New_Minor_Cat are left blank also which is not ideal.

```
#todays date string
todayDate = datetime.today().strftime("%Y.%m.%d")


########## Removing NULL values
startSeq2 = input("To start with the next section press any key or roll your face on the keyboard then PRESS ENTER")
print("Please note the next section will take a few minutes to complete, go make a cup of tea")
rmNulls = pd.read_csv (r"leads_and_dates " + todayDate + ".csv", converters={'marketing_event_id': lambda x: str(x)})

#Recasting marketing id as str for merge
#rmNulls['marketing_event_id'] = rmNulls['marketing_event_id'].replace('',0, inplace = True)
rmNulls["marketing_event_id"] = rmNulls["marketing_event_id"].astype(str)
#rmNulls.replace("NULL", value="")
print("NULLS removed")

#Order year, month, week, also correct date range limitations
rmNulls['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(rmNulls['order_date'], errors = 'coerce')
rmNulls['completed_visit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(rmNulls['completed_visit_date'], errors = 'coerce')
rmNulls["OrderYear"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(rmNulls["order_date"]).year
rmNulls["OrderMonth"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(rmNulls["order_date"]).month
rmNulls["OrderWeek"] = (rmNulls["order_date"]).dt.week

print("Order Year, Month and Week added into dataframe")

#Importing detail attribution sheet for vlookup
print("Opening detail attribution and preparing for merge")
deets = pd.read_excel(r"DetailAttr.xlsx", "Details", dtype=str)

#Isolating the 2 required cols
cherryDeets = deets[['SrcCode','New Minor Cat']].copy()
#Recasting code as str for merge
cherryDeets["SrcCode"] = cherryDeets["SrcCode"].astype(str)
print("Vlookup in Progress")
df3 = pd.merge(rmNulls,
         cherryDeets,
         left_on= "marketing_event_id",
         right_on ='SrcCode',
         how ='left')
#df3["SrcCode"].replace("", value="UNK")
print("Vlookup now completed")
```

I have tried using several different possible solutions that I've found, but these seem to overwrite everything in the event_id column.

The goal is that all those rows that lack an event_id will have the SrcCode of "UNK"

```
rmNulls['marketing_event_id'] = rmNulls['marketing_event_id'].replace('',0, inplace = True)

rmNulls.replace("NULL", value="")

df3["SrcCode"].replace("", value="UNK")
```

Current Output:

| event_id | SrcCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1852 | DIR |
| 1273 | INS |
|  |  |
| 1949 | INT |

Desired Output

| event_id | SrcCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1852 | DIR |
| 1273 | INS |
| 0 | UNK |
| 1949 | INT |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Ryan

Comment: Please share the current output and expect output. It's best if you could post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Apologies, now edited to show current vs desired output.